# Устанавливается ли Maven вместе с Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

1) В Intellij IDEA есть плагин Maven. Это программный модуль для работы с Maven или это и сеть Maven?

2) Сделать сборку (build) приложения можно и с помощью средств Intellij IDEA и с помощью Maven, или Intellij IDEA делает сборку только посредством использования Maven?

3) Есть ли у Maven свой GUI, или работать с ним принято через терминал и GUI, предоставляемый IDE?

Comment: По другим ответам предполагаю, что:
1. Maven (обычный, такой же, как можно взять с сайта Maven) устанавливается вместе с Intellij IDEA.
2. У Maven нет своего GUI.
Поправьте, пожалуйста, если не прав.

Comment: В `IDEA` уже есть `maven` и `git`. Найти их можно в файлах `IDEA`-и. Так же можно установить в систему отдельно.